# Operator(s) too many parameters for this function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Made my own string class (i.e. for homework obviously) and am getting odd syntax errors on two of my operators.  My equality and add operators claim I have too many parameters (i.e. in my .h file), but then claim the method does not even belong to the class in my .cpp file!

I even made the equality operator a friend, but the intellisense still gives me the same error messages.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong??

```
friend bool operator==(String const & left, String const & right);
```

**string.h**

```
bool operator==(String const & left, String const & right);
String const operator+(String const & lhs, String const & rhs);
```

**string.cpp**

```
bool String::operator==(String const & left, String const &right)
{
    return !strcmp(left.mStr, right.mStr);
}

String const String::operator+(String const & lhs, String const & rhs)
{
    //Find the length of the left and right hand sides of the add operator
    int lengthLhs = strlen(lhs.mStr);
    int lengthRhs = strlen(rhs.mStr);

    //Allocate space for the left and right hand sides (i.e. plus the null)
    char * buffer = new char[lhs.mStr + rhs.mStr + 1];

    //Copy left hand side into buffer
    strcpy(buffer, lhs.mStr);

    //Concatenate right hand side into buffer
    strcat(buffer, rhs.mStr);

    //Create new string
    String newString(buffer);

    //Delete buffer
    delete [] buffer;

    return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define `operator==` outside the class:

```
bool String::operator==(String const & left, String const &right)
     ^^^^^^^^ REMOVE THIS
```

If `operator+` is also a friend, it too needs to be defined as a free function (i.e. outside the class).

Comment: Same applies to `operator+`, be it `friend` or foe.

Comment: EDIT: Forgot to delete the method declaration INSIDE of my class.  All is well.  Thank you again!!