# How to Overload functions with multiple parameters? C++

Tags: c++, operators, overloading

my question is regarding an HW assignment. I tried google, contacting my teacher (never responded), with no solution.

Basically I need to overload a function that has two parameters in a header file.

Its very similar to this -> [Operator(s) too many parameters for this function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075366/operators-too-many-parameters-for-this-function)

but for some reason when I add a friend it doesn't compile.

Here is one of the functions I need to overload.

**Rational.cpp**

```
     bool reduceFractions(numbers &fractions) {
        bool answer;

        for (int i = fractions.numerator; i >= 2; i--) {       //This will keep running until i = the GFC for both numerator & denominator
            if ((((fractions.numerator % i) == 0) && (fractions.denominator % i) == 0)) {

                fractions.numerator /= i;
                fractions.denominator /= i;
                answer = true;
            }
        }

        answer = false;
        return answer;

    }

    //Adding fractions
    numbers operator+(numbers firstFraction, numbers secondFraction) {
        numbers holdFraction1, holdFraction2, someAnswers;

        //Multiply to get same denominator
        holdFraction1.denominator = firstFraction.denominator   *   secondFraction.denominator;
        holdFraction2.denominator = firstFraction.denominator   *   secondFraction.denominator;

        //Numerator multiplication to match new denominator
        holdFraction1.numerator = firstFraction.numerator     *   secondFraction.denominator;
        holdFraction2.numerator = secondFraction.numerator    *   firstFraction.denominator;

        //Adding the fractions
        someAnswers.numerator = holdFraction1.numerator + holdFraction2.numerator;
        someAnswers.denominator = holdFraction2.denominator;

        //Reduce fractions 
        while (reduceFractions(someAnswers));

        return someAnswers;
    }

istream& operator >> (istream &in, numbers &fraction) {
    char slash;
    return in >> fraction.numerator >> slash >> fraction.denominator;
    } 

    ostream& operator << (ostream& out, numbers fraction) {

        return out << fraction.numerator << "/" << fraction.denominator;
    }
```

**Rational.h**

```
    ##ifndef Rational
#define Rational


struct numbers {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};



class Math
{

private:
    numbers first, second;



public:
    Math();
    friend numbers operator+(numbers firstFraction, numbers secondFraction);
friend istream& operator >>(istream& in, numbers& fraction);
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, numbers fraction);
};


#endif
```

**Driver.cpp** the main is here

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Rational.h"




    int main() {
        numbers firstFraction, secondFraction, answerFraction;

        cout << "Enter first fraction (format a/b)";
        cin >> firstFraction;
        cout << "Enter second fraction (format a/b)";
        cin >> secondFraction;

        answerFraction = firstFraction + secondFraction;

        cout << answerFraction;


        system("Pause");

        return 0;

    }
```

**^^^** does not seem to overload the function. gives me a compile error.

I get this and several other errors

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: "struct numbers __cdecl operator+(struct numbers &,struct numbers &)" (??H@YA?AUnumbers@@AAU0@0@Z) already defined in Driver.obj C:\Users\JeanLuis\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Project1\Rational.obj  Project1
```

And if I take out *friend*
it tells me there are too many parameters...

Exactly what am I doing wrong?

Hope I made it a little more clear.

Comment: It's likely that the vast majority of this code is irrelevant to the problem, and I also don't comprehend the relevance of the [tag:c] tag?! Can you show us your [minimal testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The reason for the compiler error when you remove `friend` is that it actually is overloading the operator+ and that operator only takes one argument.

Comment: This code is not a program that I can take and try to compile to reproduce the problem. Read the page again! It is better than your original post though.

Comment: wow. the notes I took while in class are completely wrong smh then. I wrote to simply put **operator** (and whatever operator I want to overload) and it would overload the function. My ultimate goal is to overload each of my functions in the header file so I can use it in another class where the main function will be. @PaulRooney

Comment: Jean, the goal is to post *just enough* code that if you take the code you post, copy it, paste it into a file, then compile *just that file* you get exactly the error you are having problems with.  You want this to be minimal -- the least amount of code you can pull off and generate the error that is your problem.  A dump of *all* of your code is too much code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is that better? Sorry I'm very new to the forum. I made it as small as possible...

Comment: "member for 1 year, 4 months"

Comment: lol, let me rephrase that, I opened it a while ago but only recently started really using it since am taking more intensive programming courses. @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: I couldn't resist :P

Comment: " visited 13 days, 6 consecutive" in 1 year 4 months lol. thats like once every 2 months considering the last 6 were consecutive :P @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: so how would I go about overloading a function with multiple arguments? @PaulRooney

Comment: Now that you've edited the code to be consistent about reference parameters, your code no longer matches your error message. Please fix one or the other. You say there are other errors, too; is the one you've shown the *first* error you see? Always work on errors from top to bottom because early errors often compound later problems.

Comment: Your code [compiles and runs](http://ideone.com/dNNyE4) with a few changes needed to present it as a single source file.

Comment: Yeah thats how I know it works @n.m., but my teacher requires that I have three files. A header, and two .cpp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm guessing it's because your signatures don't match.

You have:

```
friend numbers operator+(numbers firstFraction, numbers secondFraction);
friend istream& operator >>(istream& in, numbers& fraction);
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, numbers fraction);
```

But your actual functions are:

```
numbers operator+(numbers &firstFraction, numbers &secondFraction) // BAD
istream& operator >> (istream &in, numbers &fraction) // GOOD
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, numbers &fraction) // BAD
```

Notice how the reference operators don't match? Fix that and see if that lets you compile. Weird convoluted errors like the one shown are often caused by things like signature mismatches.

---

**Edit Related to Comment**

*.h addition*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

*.cpp addition*

```
#include "test2.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Yeah its not that. The signatures matched at first, but then I got to the point where I was just trying random things to see if it worked... lol. For the heck of it I tried it and it still did not work. I'll edit that and fix it though. Thanks though

Comment: So, I just copied your code from post to a test project in MSVS. The only thing I had to do to get your code working was to add a few headers, which I've added to the main post. I'm assuming you just didn't put those sections, and that they're there in your code. If that's the case, try cleaning your project. If it still doesn't work, try creating a new project, and copying the files over to that new project for use.

Comment: LMAO, that was all that needed to be changed!!! Ridiculous I killed myself for an ENTIRE day because I forgot to add an include smhh.

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Less convoluted errors would be nice too. :) What IDE do you use?

Comment: I downloaded Visual Studio Professional from Microsoft since its free for students and its what I use in school. I originally wanted to use Eclipse but it got too complicated to install. Something else you recommend? @David

Comment: Nope, that was going to be it. If you pull out those includes, anything defined will be underlined like it's misspelled, and if you hover, it will tell you it's undefined.

Comment: Also, I had a whole list of errors pre-compilation indicating that.